# Is it possible to create an admin route that doesn't need the admin "key" in the URL?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, router

I created a new admin route and hooked it up to one of the admin menus for testing. When I click the menu link I go to a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/myroute/adminhtml_index/index/key/4dee0c78dec3bc0ff3cf3f3166970602/
```

Is it possible to create an admin URL/route that doesn't require that key in the URL?

Comment: do you want to access admin URL without the secret key ?

Comment: yes, i want to use an admin URL that doesn't need the secret key. is it possible?

Comment: If the answer solves your concern then please mark as right, which will help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento Admin new `secret key` is generated every time you login.

It is a unique key **32** Characters long for each session of your Magento admin login. This key is appended to the admin URL as `http://test_admin/key/78c1c0a77f2336c0b2dec9ac934af968/` 
this is only for the security reason

This option is necessary to prevent against **[CSRF attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)**

---

Sometime you may want to access admin URL **without the secret key**. For this, you can **disable** the secret key from admin URL.

**Here is how you do it:-**

---

> Go to System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Security -> Add
>   Secret Key to URLs

- – Select No
- – Save Config

Answer (score 0):

There is also the possibility to add actions which does not require the secret key. See: https://www.magento1-shop.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1/

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
     * Array of actions which can be processed without secret key validation
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_publicActions = array('view', 'index');

    public function viewAction()
    {...}
}
```